# ASP.Net Dynamic Data - Show Columns from Two Tables as Single Entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have created a new C# ASP.NET Dynamic Data Website which provides CRUD functionality for all the table entities in my EDMX file.

The following tables are in the file :

```
Customers
-----------
CustomerId 
CustomerName


Documents
-----------
DocumentId
DocumentName
DocumentType
CustomerId
```

Where CustomerId is a PK in Customers and a FK in Documents.  However When the Dynamic Web App displays all the rows in Documents I want to display the following columns in the GridView:

```
Documents
-----------
DocumentId
DocumentName
DocumentType
CustomerId 
CustomerName
```

Its important when a user sees the list of all Documents that they can also see which CustomerName is associated with each Document. I do not want to edit the CustomerName from the Documents list. Its just to help with viewing.  How can I see CustomerName from Document GridView in Dynamic Data Web App?

I used Code First From Database with VS2012, here is the entities generated from EF :

```
namespace DocMappings
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Customers
    {
        public Customers()
        {
            this.Documents = new HashSet<Documents >();
        }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Documents> Documents { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

And the Documents Entity is:

```
namespace DocMappings
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Documents
    {            
        public int DocumentId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public int DocumentType{ get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }


        public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; }         
    }
}
```

Comment: I've read that I can't use a complex type, which is the only way I can think of.

Comment: Well we've got no way of knowing what you can/can't use as we don't even know what language you are working in! You need to give more context and some code that can be used as a basis to help.

Comment: Point taken -  I've now added the entities now so it should be clearer

Comment: So `Documents` contains many `Document` objects? Is that important or are you not worrying about them at this point?

Comment: Hi David, I've removed the ICollection as it was not correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an anonymous type for the data:

```
var docs = context.Documents.SelectMany(d => new 
    {
        d.DocumentId,
        d.DocumentName,
        d.DocumentType,
        d.CustomerId,
        d.Customer.CustomerName 
    });
```

Alternatively, it is likely preferable to put this into a concrete class:

```
public class CustomerDocument
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    public int DocumentType { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName  { get; set; }
}
```

And get the data with a slight modification:

```
List<CustomerDocument> docs = context.Documents.SelectMany(d => new CustomerDocument
    {
        d.DocumentId,
        d.DocumentName,
        d.DocumentType,
        d.CustomerId,
        d.Customer.CustomerName 
    });
```

Comment: OK, and how will I get this to display with Dynamic Data?

Comment: As my understanding is that is that by default the gridivew only displays tables.